# Make 3 spans fill exactly one line

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have the following Problem:

I have a line in a document with a given width.

Now I have 3 elements, from which one is an `<a>` and two are `<span>`.

The `<a>` tag contains a string which has no fixed width. So the `<a>` will have different widths.

The third element, which is a `<span>`, has a fixed width and has to be at the right border of the container of the three.

The second element, which is the first `<span>`, should exactly fit in the middle.

[image: view]

Until now I did not find any way to achieve this. I know it is probably possible with a table, but that does not seem to be the right way to do it. I am sure there is a CSS-solution too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to add to `display:table;` option, you have `display:flex;`  or the `float`ting method revisited with a negative `margin` for old browsers:  **[DEMO *(both methods)*](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wKBpH)**

Flex:

HTML

```
<p class="flex"><a href="#"> text as long as needed </a>
<span class="middle">
   text with any width text with any width text with any width text with any width 
</span>
  <span> span </span>
</p>
```

CSS

```
.flex {
  display:flex;
}
.middle {
  flex:2;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

---

`float`tish trick:

HTML

```
<p class="funny"><a href="#"> text as long as needed </a>
<span class="right"> span </span>
<span class="layout">
  <span> text with any width text with any width text with any width text with any width </span>
</span>
</p>
```

CSS

```
a {
  float:left;
  background:#2EAF2E;
  color:#2B3A23;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.right {
  float:right;
  color:white;
  background:#333;
}
.layout {
  display:block;
  overflow:hidden;
  background:#AA2425;
  color:#2B3A23;
}
.layout span {
  display:inline-block;
  margin-right:-9999px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`display:table` and `display:table-cell` are your friend. And very cross browser compatible. Also can make use of `vertical-align: middle`.

Here's a demo:

http://jsbin.com/tofewa/1/edit

Comment: the first `<span>` is not exactly wrapping its content